# PHP MySQL session_set_save_handler race condition

Tags: php, mysql, session, locking, race-condition

I have written a simple [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) using a MySQL innoDB table as the storage backend. MySQL is 5.5.

Code looks like so (very simplified, but hopefully illustrates the flow of code), I am using [RedBean ORM](http://www.redbeanphp.com/) for interacting with the database, but the commands should be clear in showing what was being written, read or deleted.:

```
class MySession{

    private $_database;  

    public function  __construct($database){
       //database object is injected using dependency injection then assigned to private var

       //Hook up handlers
       session_set_save_handler(
        array($this, "open"),
        array($this, "close"),
        array($this, "read"),
        array($this, "write"),
        array($this, "destroy"),
        array($this, "garbageCollection"));
       }

       //Register the shutdown function
       register_shutdown_function('session_write_close'); 

       //start
       session_start();

       //Regenerate session id
       //(NOTE: in production code, the id is regenerated every 10 minutes,
       //but regenerating allows us to trigger the race condition for demonstration.
       session_regenerate_id(TRUE);

    public function open($savePath, $sessionName){
        $this->_database->exec('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE');
        $this->_database->begin(); //Begin Transaction
        return true;
    }   

    public function close(){
        $this->_database->commit(); //Commit the transaction
        return true;
    }

    public function read($id){

        $this->_database->exec('SELECT * FROM session WHERE identifier = ? LOCK IN SHARE MODE', array($id));
        $session = $this->_database->findOne('session', 'identifier = ?', array($id));
        return $session->data;
    }

    public function write($id, $sessionData){

        $this->_database->exec('SELECT * FROM session WHERE identifier = ? FOR UPDATE', array($id));
        $session = $this->_database->findOne('session', 'identifier = ?', array($id));

        //We need to create a new session
        if ($session == NULL){
            $session = $this->_database->dispense('session');
        }

        $this->_database->store($session);
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function destroy($id){
        $this->_database->exec('SELECT * FROM session WHERE identifier = ? FOR UPDATE', array($id));
        $session = $this->_database->findOne('session', 'identifier = ?', array($id));

        if ($session != NULL){
            $this->_database->trash($session);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function garbageCollection($maxlifetime){
        $old = ... //Calculate the time for expired sessions

        $this->_database->exec("DELETE from session WHERE last_activity < ?", array($old));
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

The problem is that even with the locking in place, if I send multiple requests to the application (for example, using AJAX), the race condition still occurs and the data stored in the session is lost. I have pinned it down to `session_regenerate_id(TRUE)`, which deletes the previous session to being the cause of the issue. However, even with the row locking, the issue still occurs.

I have looked at this [page](http://thwartedefforts.org/2006/11/11/race-conditions-with-ajax-and-php-sessions/), as well as some [code](http://race.phux.net/code/session_mysqlsesslock.phps) from that author, but that uses MyISAM tables which implements table locking.

Can anyone shed some light as to why the locking is not making a difference and perhaps offer some solutions to this problem?

Comment: `session_regenerate_id` is always problematic and susceptible to race conditions on the client. Are you sure it's not the inherent cookie-update-timing problem, rather than database-level problems?

Comment: I am not sure about that actually, now that you mention it. Is there a way to dbug and check for the cookie update timing problem?

Comment: That's tricky and a lot of fun. ;) Use a lot of logging and network traffic introspection to see who sends what where when.

Comment: Just did some crude testing and I can indeed comfirm that that's an issue with the cookie update. Are there any solutions to that?

Comment: It's an inherent problem in having only one valid session id at a time and changing the id upon each request, which is made even worse if you add asynchronous requests. I'd get rid of `session_regenerate_id`...

Comment: :( If I remove `session_regenerate_id`, are there other alternatives to prevent against session hijacking?

Comment: Secure connections via SSL. :) Changing session ids does not necessarily protect against session hijacking, it just reduces the window of opportunity. A hijacker can very quickly automatically hijack a session though, locking the real user out.

Comment: Had the same problem, and commenting out `session_regenerate_id()` totally fixed the issue. I was tearing my hair out, halfway through rewriting my login script... wish I'd found this question yesterday. I don't think it's a big loss, considering I am gonna implement SSL anyway later on >facepalm< Anyway it's not like I'm guarding the nuclear launch codes or anything. THANK YOU, @deceze and @F21!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is to only regenerate the session ID when you know the request is a full-page request, rather than an AJAX request.

```
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {
    session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
}
```

The above assumes the javascript library you're using sets the header.